# Pentaho: establish a connection using mutual authentication

Tags: pentaho, keystore, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to configure Pentaho using a mutual authentication to service now.
I've a public key and a private key but I'm getting "User not authenticated"

I set up the following configuration in Postman:

- Added a client certificate: Host, crt (public key .pem file), key (private key .pem file)
- GET: https://URL
- Header: Content-Type, Accept and Interface

With this configuration I can access the data.

I need to replicate the same in Pentaho. I've this (not sure if it's correct):

- with both files (public and private key) I've generated a .p12 file and added to my keystore
- Rest client in pentaho with the URL, Header = Header in postman
  I will get a message "User not Authenticated"